# Python Convert m4a File to Another Format

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a way to convert a .m4a file to another format such as .wav. I used the module, SpeechRecognition, but it didn't work. My file did show up in my print statement, so I know the file went through. My code is below. Please help and thank you!

```
print(file)
song = AudioSegment.from_m4a(file)
song.export("audioexport.wav", format="wav")
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'AudioSegment' has no attribute 'from_m4a'
```

Comment: Why use python for this, though? Just use ffmpeg, which is by far the best tool for media conversion, use that to convert your on-disk data to the format you need, and then load _that_ into Python?

Answer (score 0):

```
from_m4a
```

is not a function. I don't think m4a is supported. Try a different format, and then use the `from_file` function:

```
AudioSegment.from_file(file, "mp3")
```

see this: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub

Answer (score 0):

```
#Import Library

from pydub import AudioSegment

#f1.m4a is the m4a file in current directory. f1.wav name of wav file to write
AudioSegment.from_file("f1.m4a",format = 'm4a').export("f1.wav", format='wav')
```

This code returns an AudioSegment object of the f1.m4a file.
AudioSegment.from_file("f1.m4a",format = 'm4a')

Instead of declaring a local variable and then calling the export method, you can call the method directly from the returned object by adding:
.export("f1.wav", format='wav')

In other words, it this the same as the following code:

myAudioSegment = AudioSegment.from_file("f1.m4a",format = 'm4a')

myAudioSegment.export("f1.wav", format='wav')

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**